# Wrong previous value when reading from Arduino

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm using QT to read value from a photo-resistor connected to the Arduino board, I successfully read the value and emit it, as the following:

```
void Dialog::handleReadyRead(){
    QString temp;
    temp = serial.readAll();
    serialBuffer.append(temp);
    int serPos;
    double tempValue;
    double previousValue = tempValue;
    while ((serPos = serialBuffer.indexOf('\n')) >= 0)
    {
        bool ok;
        previousValue = tempValue;
        tempValue =     QString::fromLatin1(serialBuffer.left(serPos)).toDouble(&ok);
        if (ok){
            emit newData(tempValue, previousValue);
        }
        serialBuffer = serialBuffer.mid(serPos+1);
    }
}
```

However, for some reason I need to get the previous value. When I do `previousValue = tempValue`, it prints out some weird values (sometimes it is indeed the previous value, but for most time it just print out 0 or some number really close to 0). I would like to know what had happened here and how could I fix it?

Sample wrong output may be like:

```
399
399
399
399
399
399
399
399
399
399
399
399
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1.49189e-154
1.49189e-154
0
0
0
```

399 is the correct value while all 0s are not.

Comment: Your variable tempValue is never issued a value to begin with, then you try assigning previousValue to tempValue.

Comment: this still happened when I initialize it with a 0, and it does not give mw a correct value when I do double tempValue = QString::fromLatin1(serialBuffer.left(serPos)).toDouble();

Comment: Is there ever a situation where all 0s are not the correct output?

What happens when the photoresistor detects nothing?

Comment: Thanks. the photoresistor should always have a non-zero value in this case as it can always detect the light from the window, this value should change dramatically when I use a laser pointer to shine on it.

Comment: What's the rest of your code look like?

Comment: What Im doing is to make a realtime plot tool using QT, in addition, I am trying to measure the duration when the laser pointer is shining on the photoresistor, and thats why I need previous value.

Comment: I also noticed your bool ok is not set to anything either.

Comment: I changed it to false as an initial value and it still doesn't work

Comment: What exactly is emit? Is this your own defined class? And I assume you only want to output values when both tempValue and previousValue are not empty or 0?

Comment: what emit does is that whoever there is a data coming in , it will emit the data. I have another function that receives the emit data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
double tempValue = 0;
double previousValue = 0;

while ((serPos = serialBuffer.indexOf('\n')) >= 0)
{
    tempValue = QString::fromLatin1(serialBuffer.left(serPos)).toDouble(&ok);

    if (previousValue != 0 && tempValue != 0){
        emit newData(tempValue, previousValue);
    }

    previousValue = tempValue
    serialBuffer = serialBuffer.mid(serPos+1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I kinda see whats happening here, but the problem is that 0 is not something from the resistor, it's just abnormal values caused by initializations(I found that later on). this part doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh ok good to know you solved it.

Next time though post all the code relevant to your problem :)

But nonetheless my answer fixes the problem with the code you posted if that helps.

Comment: just found out what the problem but still not able to solve it... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming whenever `(true != ok)` your value in invalid. The problem might be there, you keep that value while you should discard it.

What about you do

```
bool ok;
double parsed = QString::fromLatin1(serialBuffer.left(serPos)).toDouble(&ok);
if (ok) {
    previousValue = tempValue;
    tempValue = parsed;
    emit newData(parsed, previousValue);      
    }
```

It might be relevant to rename `tempValue` to `currValue` in that example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is "parsed" here? is it a new variable other than tempValue?

Comment: Yes, parsed is a new variable. the idea is that you want to discard the value whenever 'ok' is false.
First of all, your current code doesn't set 'previousValue' or 'currentValue' = 0, which means the first values you get are most likely garbage. The second issue was 'previousValue = currentValue' even though the value isn't valid (you assign it before checking 'ok').